# Highstock smooth panning

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to achieve smooth panning on a simple highstock chart by clicking in the plot area and dragging the cursor.

I noticed that it works very well if my data is not timestamped :

```
data: [-25.1,-23.8,-19.9,-19.1,-19.1,-20.7,-20.7,-21.6,-21.6,-22.2,-22.2,-22.6,-22.6,-22.9,-22.9,-23.2,-23.2,-23.7,-23.8,-23.8,-24,-24,-24.1,-24.2,-24.2,-24.4,-24.5,-25.7,-25.8,-25.8,-25.8,-25.2,-25.2,-25.3,-25.3,-25.4,-25.5,-25.5,-25.5,-25.5,-25.6,-25.6,-25.2,-24.6,-24.6,-24.2,-24.2,-24.8,-25.1,-25.1,-25.3,-25.3,-25.4]
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/jhartnag/vrq396ja/

However as soon as I add timestamps, then the panning stops being continuous and pans by increments : https://jsfiddle.net/jhartnag/e8w72o4z/

(On top of that the navigator window seems to change but that's another problem I guess)

**How can I achieve smooth panning with timestamped data in Highstock ?**

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by setting `ordinal : false` on the axis :

`xAxis : {
    ...
    ordinal : false
  }`